# Crash while calling setItemWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am using a QTreeWidget and setting a widget for the QTreeWidgetItem in the QTreeWidget. It is working fine but when I do the same for second time, the application is crashing.

The below is working fine.

```
QTreeWidget* treewidget = new QTreeWidget();
QTreeWidgetItem* item0 = new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList(QString("item0")));
treewidget->insertTopLevelItem(0,item0);
QSlider* slider0 = new QSlider();
treewidget->setItemWidget(item0, 0, slider0);
```

But if I add the last line once again, it is crashing when running the application.

The below is crashing.

```
QTreeWidget* treewidget = new QTreeWidget();
QTreeWidgetItem* item0 = new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList(QString("item0")));
treewidget->insertTopLevelItem(0,item0);
QSlider* slider0 = new QSlider();
treewidget->setItemWidget(item0, 0, slider0);
treewidget->setItemWidget(item0, 0, slider0);       // Intentionally added to simulate the issue
```

The above is an example to show the issue, but in my application, based on some events, I delete the tree widget items and add it later. When I set the item widget (after adding the items later), I am getting the crash.

I could not figure out why. Any ideas? FYI, I am using Qt 5.3.2 MSVC 2010, 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
treewidget->setItemWidget(item0, 0, slider0);
treewidget->setItemWidget(item0, 0, slider0);// Intentionally added to simulate the issue
```

I look at Qt code (4.x):

```
void QTreeWidget::setItemWidget(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_D(QTreeWidget);
    QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget(d->index(item, column), widget);
}
```

and `QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`:

```
void QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget(const QModelIndex &index, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractItemView);
    if (!d->isIndexValid(index))
        return;
    if (QWidget *oldWidget = indexWidget(index)) {
        d->persistent.remove(oldWidget);
        d->removeEditor(oldWidget);
        oldWidget->deleteLater();
    }
```

so if you add slider0 two times, then at first call it was added,
at seconds call Qt call for it `deleteLater`, and then added it,
are sure that this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set correct `parent` in the constructor of `QTreeWidgetItem`. Try this:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* item0 = new QTreeWidgetItem(treewidget);
```

Also it is important to understand who is owner of the `slider0` after calling of `setItemWidget()`: the owner is your table, so 1) you don't need to delete this object; 2) the object will be deleted if you call `setItemWidget` for the same cell again. So, double call of `treewidget->setItemWidget(item0, 0, slider0);` seems very strange (second time you are setting the deleted object into that cell).

Comment: @Sankar, ok, but it is important to set correct parent any way. I've extended my answer (see details in the user1034749's answer)

Comment: @llya, actually I am trying to implement a property window which contains a tree widget. Each tree widget item contains a widget (set using setItemWidget() ). The property window shows property of object i am selecting. Let's say the tree widget is showing the properties of Object A, I am selecting Object B and when I select the Object A again, I am removing the items in the tree widget (which actually belongs to Object B) and adding the Object A items again. When i do this, it is not having the item widget i set initially. So i am setting the item widget again, which is causing the crash.

Comment: What does "which actually belongs to Object B" means? If it means "which actually corresponds to" it is ok (i.e. if you create new widgets before calling of `setItemWidget`). But if you are using pointers on that objects (parts of Object B) as arguments of `setItemWidget` it is wrong, because in this case you are losing ownership (and this is the reason of the crash).

Comment: No i am not using pointers of Object B as arguments for 'setItemWidget'. I was using the same widget as argument for 'setItemWidget' two times. As you said, it is deleted when i call 'setItemWidget' second time. It could be a reason for the crash. Anyway, i have to look fir different approach for my use case. Thanks!